# Javascript jquery for loop problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

When i run this for loop it gives me the name bob and for jacob it says undefined does anyone have any idea why?

```
        $(function(){

        count = 1;

        for(x=0; x <= count; x++)
        {
            track = $('#track' + x).val();
            document.write(track);
        }

    });

    <input type="hidden" id="track0" value="bob" /> 
<input type="hidden" id="track1" value="jacob" />
```

Comment: Are you putting quotes around your identifier? Make sure they are being added around the number too and not just #track

Comment: Just an advise: input fields should be always called by his name, not by his id (even though it works fine).

Answer (score 3):

Writing to document deletes your previous HTML. So , you cannot access the element by id anymore.
Alerting or writing it to some div instead of document gives proper response.

http://jsfiddle.net/KjHFM/

```
<span id='test'> RESULT : </span>


 $(function(){

    count = 1;

    for(x=0; x <= count; x++)
    {
        track = $('#track' + x).val();
        alert(track); // or $('#test').append(track+ "    ");
    }


});
```

Comment: This is not jQuery but just plain javascript that triggers when jquery is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Because `document.write()` replaces old html, it means that track1 is deleted with first `.write()`

Works [here](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/9aa3b) with alert

```
<script>        $(function(){

        count = 1;

        for(x=0; x <= count; x++)
        {
        $("#content").append(x+' is '+$('#track' + x).val());
        }

    });</Script>
<div id="content"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="track0" value="bob" /> 
<input type="hidden" id="track1" value="jacob" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time you call document.write you are replacing the dom with the html text bob

When the second iteraction runs in the for loop jacob is not in the dom anymore - this is why undefined is written.

Also as you are not using the var keyword x, count and track are now all global variables of the window object.

Answer (score 0):

document.write() alters the DOM in a very agressive way, replacing the original content.

Correct jQuery notation would be:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("input").each(function( index ){
        alert( index + ': ' + $(this).get(0).id + ' = ' + $(this).val() );
    });
});
```

You could add the text you're now seeing in the alert boxes to the body by replacing the alert line with the following:

```
$("body").append( index + ': ' + $(this).get(0).id + ' = ' + $(this).val() );
```